# Dots (...) com titulo em variavel

Tags: r

Preciso rodar uma função do tipo

```
f <- function(...) {
  l <- list(...)
  l[["hortela"]]
}

x <- 'hortela'
```

Se fizermos

```
f(hortela = 1)
```

temos o resultado `1`, que é o esperado.

Como faço para chamar `f()` usando `x` ao invés de escrever `hortela` manualmente?

PS: não quero modificar a `f()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver usando `do.call` e uma lista nomeada.

```
do.call(f, setNames(list(1), x))
```

does the work.